# Perl Copy to more than one Location

Tags: perl, while-loop, copy

Hello I'm attempting to copy a file to more then one location. I have written a script that will copy files using File::Find and File::Copy together to one location but I can not get the script to copy to a second or third location. I've tried to add a second variable target2 to the script so I can also copy the JPG files to this second target location. When I try to do this I get an error message. I want the copy to run on a loop that will copy the files X amount of seconds so I added the sleep function in as well. Can anyone explain to me why I can't copy to more than one location or help me find a way to do this? Thank you.

```
   while (1)
   { sleep (10);
    find(
       sub {
         if (-f &&/\.jpg$/i) {
           print "$File::Find::name -> $target, $target2";
           copy($File::Find::name, $target ,$target2)
            or die(q{copy failed:} . $!);

            }
           },
           @source
             ); 

            }
```

Error message: Bad Buffer size for copy: 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

copy function can't copy to 2 destinations. Call it twice:

```
copy($File::Find::name, $target);
copy($File::Find::name, $target2);
```

Look here to see the parameters explanation: http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html#SYNOPSIS

As the docs say:

> An optional third parameter can be used to specify the buffer size
>   used for copying. This is the number of bytes from the first file,
>   that will be held in memory at any given time, before being written to
>   the second file.

So, when you specified the third parameter, Perl understood, that you want to set the buffer size manually. But you gave a string instead of a number, so it converted the string to a number: 0, and gave you an error:

> Bad Buffer size for copy: 0